# javascript delay between adding text to a div

Tags: javascript

I want to use Javascript to add a text to a html element (such as the p tag) 15 times and it must wait one second every time it adds the text.

I tried some ways and didn't get the proper result. It adds all 15 texts after 15 seconds.

What should I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var interval = setInterval(function(){
         if(i <= 14){
              element.innerHTML += "sometext";
              }else{
            clearInterval(interval);
           }
        i++;
 },1000);
```

Comment: I need to do it using javascript , not jquery.

Comment: @MJNaderi yep sorry, now is fixed

Answer (score 1):

This is a functional approach using setTimeout

```
function addText(text,total) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        total--;
        if(total == 0) {
         return true;   
        }
       addText(text,total);        
    },1000);

    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML += text;
}
```

Usage:

```
addText("sometext",15);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HNpQp/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;    
var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");

var interval = setInterval(function(){
     if(i <= 14){
          element.innerHTML += "sometext";
          }else{
        clearInterval(interval);
       }
    i++;

 },1000);
```

innerHTML is not a method